# LINQ, Filtrar por Fechas, contar cuantas veces se repite una fecha y mostrar la Fecha

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta entre dos tablas:

```
traza(
     Idlote int 
     FechaFinDigitalizada DateTime
)
```

```
Documento(
     iddocumento int
     Idlote int
     eliminada int 
)
```

He intentado hacer esta consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo malo es que la fecha tiene el formato **`YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm:ss`** y eso complica el *distinct*.

```
var query = (from traza in db.TrazabilidadLote.Where(f => f.FechaInicioDigitalizado >= 
     FechaInicio && 
     f.FechaInicioDigitalizado <= FechaFin)
     join doc in db.Documento.Where(d => d.Eliminada != 1)
         on traza.IdLote equals doc.idlote into contar
         
     select new{

         año = traza.FechaFinDigitalizado.Year,
         mes = traza.FechaFinDigitalizado.Month,
         dia = traza.FechaFinDigitalizado.Day,
         contar = contar.Count()
     })
     .ToList();
```

Quiero un resultado similar a este.

> 464  2021/04/01
> 566  2021/04/02
> 652  2021/04/03
> 102  2021/04/04

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo para que se te entienda mejor

Comment: Otra pregunta, las dos tablas están relacionadas a través de propiedades de navegación?

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultado = from t in db.TrazabilidadLote.ToList()
                where t.Documento.Eliminada != 1 &&
                t => t.FechaInicioDigitalizado >= FechaInicio && 
                t.FechaInicioDigitalizado <= FechaFin
                group t by t.FechaInicioDigitalizado == null ? 
                           new DateTime(1, 1, 1) : 
                           t.FechaInicioDigitalizado.Date into grupo
                select new
                {
                   Fecha = grupo.key,
                   Total = grupo.Count()
                };
```

En esta consulta filtramos mediante la **claúsula** **where** por las condiciones deseadas, que en tu caso son que el documento no esté eliminado y que la **propiedad FechaInicioDigitalizado** esté en el rango de fechas.

```
t.Documento.Eliminada != 1 &&
t => t.FechaInicioDigitalizado >= FechaInicio && 
t.FechaInicioDigitalizado <= FechaFin
```

Fíjate que no se utiliza el **join**, ya que al estar asociados estos objetos, puedes acceder a ellos mediante sus **propiedades de navegación**(ventajas de **Linq** y la **Programación Orientada a Objetos**)

```
t.Documento.Eliminada//Como Traza está asociada a Documento, esta es la forma en la que accederías al documento de la traza.
```

Después agrupamos mediante la **claúsula** **group** a través de:

```
t.FechaInicioDigitalizado.Date
```

Aquí se hace uso de la **función** **Date**, la cual solo nos devolverá la parte de la fecha, es decir se obviará la parte de la hora(**hh:mm:ss**).

Un grupo es algo así como una pareja **llave/valor**, donde la **llave** es el elemento que nos va a servir para hacer la agrupación y el **valor** serían todos los elementos que tienen en común esa **llave**. En tu caso la **llave** sería cada fecha y el **valor** serían todos los elementos que tienen en común esa fecha.

Por último se devuelve un **objeto anónimo** **de 2 propiedades, Fecha y Total**, donde **Fecha** es precisamente la llave de la agrupación, es decir la fecha, y **Total** sería la cantidad de elementos que tienen en común esta fecha, para hallar el total de elementos que tienen en común dicha fecha se aplica la **función** **Count**.

Para imprimir esta consulta sería:

```
foreach(var r in resultado)
{
   Console.Write(r.Fecha.ToString() + ": ");
   Console.Write(r.Total.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Hacemos un **ciclo foreach** y vamos imprimiendo en pantalla por cada **Fecha** su respectivo **Total**. Obtendríamos algo como esto:

Fecha1: Total1

Fecha2: Total2

...

En caso de que el campo por el que vamos a agrupar tenga nulos deberíamos poner algo como esto:

```
group t by t.FechaInicioDigitalizado == null ? 
           new DateTime(1, 1, 1) : 
           t.FechaInicioDigitalizado.Date into grupo
```

De esta forma preguntamos si **t.FechaDigitalizado es null** y de serlo asumiríamos que una fecha con valor nulo es una con el formato **1/1/1**, de no ser nulo pues agrupamos por **t.FechaInicioDigitalizado.Date**.

Comment: perdona, lo acabo de comprobar y no tiene llave foranea, al parecer el creador de la BD no las relacionó.

Comment: @jcmh, pues debería tener llave foránea, sino sería un mal diseño de base de datos

Comment: @jcmh, en un rato corrijo el problema de la fecha, te aviso

Comment: @jcmh, ya está arreglado se le añadió el método ToList() en db .trazabilidadLote.ToList(), de esta forma se maneja la consulta como una lista de objetos, aunque hay otras formas de hacerlo,  adapta esto a la consulta que hiciste, aunque no haya llave foránea debe servir, aunque te repito lo ideal sería que hubieran llaves foraneas

Comment: Me dice que esta mal otra columna FechaFinAsignacion de la tabla Traza, que es una columna que ni llamo, ni filtro que no uso en ningún momento de la consulta.

Comment: @jcmh, dime que error te sale

Comment: Nada, la persona que creo las tablas, la escribió mal. Información adicional: No se puede establecer la propiedad 'FechaInicioPreparado' de 'TrazabilidadLote' en un valor 'null'. Debe establecer esta propiedad en un valor que no sea NULL de tipo 'System.DateTime'.  --> me dice este error ahora, cuando se crea la tupla hay valores que me los crea Null, ¿hay alguna manera que al realizar la consulta no importe si son null o no estos campos?

Comment: @jcmh, esa propiedad de fechaInicioPreparado, de donde sale pq no la veo por ninguna parte en tus consultas, otra pregunta, tu puedes modificar la estructura de la base de datos?

Comment: No, FechaInicioPreparado no se toca en ningún momento, pero es otra columna de la tabla Trazabilidad en algún lugar de la tabla tiene el valor null. No puedo modificar la estructura tiene muchos datos la tabla y ya el sistema ya esta trabajando con esta estructura hace bastante.

Comment: @jcmh, revisa lo nuevo q puse en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Hice estos cambios en la consulta

```
  var query = (from t in db.TrazabilidadLote
                    join doc in db.Documento on t.IdLote equals doc.idlote
                    where doc.Eliminada != 1 && 
                    t.FechaInicioDigitalizado >= FechaInicio && 
                    t.FechaInicioDigitalizado <= FechaFin
                    group t by t.FechaInicioDigitalizado.Date into grupo
                    select new
                                {
                                   Fecha = grupo.Key,
                                   Total = grupo.Count()
                    }).ToList();
```

Cuando pongo .Date en Group by me da el siguiente error:

Información adicional: El miembro de tipo especificado 'Date' no se admite en LINQ to Entities. Solo se admiten inicializadores, miembros de entidades y propiedades de navegación de entidades.

si le quito el .Date no filtra por fecha y me devuelve estos datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hice estos cambios y me muestra bien lo que quiero, al parecer el hecho de que haya columnas con datos Null no permite realizar la consulta y me iba diciendo tal columna (que no uso en ningún momento) tiene valor Null. Para solucionar esto quite de los modelos todas las columnas que no voy a utilizar en ninguna consulta.

```
  var query = (from t in db.TrazabilidadLote.ToList()
                     join doc in db.Documento on t.IdLote equals doc.idlote
                     where doc.Eliminada != 1 &&
                     t.FechaInicioDigitalizado >= FechaInicio &&
                     t.FechaInicioDigitalizado <= FechaFin
                     group t by t.FechaInicioDigitalizado.Date
                     into grupo
                     select new
                     {
                         Fecha = grupo.Key.Date.ToShortDateString(),
                         Total = grupo.Count()
                     }).ToList();
```

solo cuando puse Date.ToShortDateString() puso la fecha en el formato que deseo.

```
grupo.Key.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

así quedo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias japv!

Comment: Si tu respuesta es correcta marcarla como aceptada, y si la mía te ayudo y es correcta te agradecería un voto, gracias